# Getting error while dynamically providing input,output path

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have created a multi-file reader and flat file writer (Later, I have to extend it to multifile read to multiple file write, one to one mapping). When i provide the input path through property file, It works all good, but when I try to provide path through jobExecutionContext it starts giving me error. What surprises me is that writer is successfully taking the path from executionContext and writing whatever location i provide but not the reader.

PS: I am using "SingleItemPeekableItemReader" because the data i have in file is multi-line record and has no way to determine when one record ends . the only way to know that record 2 has started is when you have access to next line and you know that its start of new record.

Can someone through some light, What wrong i am doing.

```
<bean id="itemReader" class="com.varun.reader.AccountDataReader">
    <property name="fieldSetReader"         ref="PeekableitemReader" />
    <property name="headerFieldSetMapper"   ref="headerFieldSetMapper" />
    <property name="multiReader"            ref="multiResourceReader"/>
</bean>

<bean id="PeekableitemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.SingleItemPeekableItemReader" >
    <property name="delegate" ref="multiResourceReader"/>
</bean>

<bean id="multiResourceReader"  class=" org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader" >
    <property name="resources" value="file:${file.input.dir}*.DAT" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="fileItemReader" />
</bean>

<bean id="fileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer" ref="accountDataTokenizer"/>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PassThroughFieldSetMapper" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="comments" value=""></property>
</bean>
```

It error out, when i provide the resources in multiresourceReader as below

```
<property name="resources" value="file:#{JobExecutionContext[input_dir]}*.DAT" />
```

Error logs as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'step1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'itemReader' while setting bean property 'itemReader'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemReader' defined in class path resource [spring/config/process-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'PeekableitemReader' while setting bean property 'fieldSetReader'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'PeekableitemReader' defined in class path resource [spring/config/process-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'multiResourceReader' while setting bean property 'delegate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multiResourceReader' defined in class path resource [spring/config/process-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'JobExecutionContext' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
```

after making multireader scope as step i am getting error as below.I have tried putting scope on all the other delegate readers as well, but i am getting the same error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'step1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'itemReader' while setting bean property 'itemReader'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemReader' defined in class path resource [spring/config/process-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11 implementing org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamReader,org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStream,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader] for property 'multiReader'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11 implementing org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamReader,org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStream,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader] for property 'multiReader': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.varun.JobScheduler.main(JobScheduler.java:9)
```

My custom Reader

```
public class AccountDataReader implements ItemReader<AccountDataBO> {
private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(AccountDataReader.class);
private boolean recordFinished;

private AccountDataBO acctObj = new AccountDataBO();

private SingleItemPeekableItemReader<FieldSet> fieldSetReader;
private HeaderFieldSetMapper headerFieldSetMapper;
private MultiResourceItemReader<FieldSet> multiReader;

@Override
public AccountDataBO read() throws Exception {
    recordFinished = false;

    while (!recordFinished) {
        process(fieldSetReader.read());
    }
    AccountDataBO result = acctObj;
    acctObj = new AccountDataBO();

    return result;
}

private void process(FieldSet fieldSet) throws Exception {

    if (fieldSet == null) {
        log.debug("FINISHED Reading");
        recordFinished = true;
        acctObj=null;
        return;
    }

    String lineId = fieldSet.readString(0);

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(lineId) && lineId.contains(AccountDataBO.ACCOUNT)) {
        log.debug("Starting new Record");
        acctObj.setHeader(headerFieldSetMapper.mapFieldSet(fieldSet));
        acctObj.setResource(multiReader.getCurrentResource());

    }

    //Code

}

private void CheckEOFNewAccount() throws Exception {
    if ((fieldSetReader.peek() != null
            && ((fieldSetReader.peek().getValues())[0].contains(AccountDataBO.ACCOUNT)))
            || fieldSetReader.peek() == null) {
        log.debug("Next Line is Account or EOF Hence returning for current Account");
        recordFinished = true;
        return;
    }
}

public void setFieldSetReader(SingleItemPeekableItemReader<FieldSet> fieldSetReader) {
    this.fieldSetReader = fieldSetReader;
}

public void setHeaderFieldSetMapper(HeaderFieldSetMapper headerFieldSetMapper) {
    this.headerFieldSetMapper = headerFieldSetMapper;
}

public void setMultiReader(MultiResourceItemReader<FieldSet> multiReader) {
    this.multiReader = multiReader;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to inject job parameters into a batch component, the component needs to be step scoped.  So in your example, change this:

```
<bean id="multiResourceReader"  
      class=" org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader" >
```

To this:

```
<bean id="multiResourceReader"  
      class=" org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader" 
      scope="step" >
```

Comment: It again error-out when i scoped the multi reader as step. Updated the logs in main question.

Comment: Your custom `ItemReader` seems to be expecting a specific implementation instead of just an `ItemReader`.  Code to the interface and your additional error should go away.

Comment: I mean the setter on your `AccountDataReader` (`AccountDataReader#set MultiReader`) is looking for a `MultiResourceItemReader` instead of just an `ItemReader` or `ItemStreamReader`.  Change that to take an `ItemReader` or change your step scope to proxy mode `TARGET_CLASS` and your error should go away.

Comment: My Item reader has below signature public class AccountDataReader implements ItemReader<AccountDataBO> { and i m injecting a SinglePeekableReader to read the file. I have explained above why i need SinglePeekableReader.                                                                                           Please advise what need to be implemented. Thanks.

Comment: NOt sure if I understood you correctly. I have added my reader class as above. Do you see any descripency

Comment: @ Michael Minella : Thanks for the help. I could figure out the mistake i was doing. In my reader#set method i was using SingleItemPeekableReader whereas i should be using ItemReader Interface and later i can convert that reader in peekable reader. Thanks for your help.